# Optimised loop for array using ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have (m = rows-1, n = cols-1) dimensional matrix.

And I passing **i** to method which will return array in following manner (provided with `i <= m,n`)

Suppose n=0, so for 4x4 matrix, it will return boundary elements position.

**Do not consider below as ruby syntax, get only flow.**

```
square = [[i,i] -> [i, m-i] -> [n-i, m-1] -> [n-i, i] -> [i,i]]
```

(no data is repeated in above)

I achieved above in recursion manner by setting parameters but I need easier/optimised trick.

**Update** - for user sawa

```
arr = [*1..16].each_slice(4).to_a
m,n = arr.length-1, arr[0].length-1

loop_count = 0

output = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [3, 2], [2, 2], [1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]

loop_count = 1

output = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Your notation `..` is not clear. Does that represent a `Range` object (in which case your example is invalid), or are they meant to be ellipsis (in which case you are missing commas in between the items, and using three periods `...` rather than two `..` are standard)?

Comment: Do you **have** a matrix from the beginning (as you wrote), or are you trying to **generate** one? Even that is not clear.

Comment: What does `rows` and `cols` mean in `(m = rows-1, n = cols-1)`?

Comment: Given that you have an (m, n) matrix, in your `Suppose n=0, so for 4x4 matrix` case, shouldn't it be `mx0` matrix rather than `4x4`? Not clear what `n` means here.

Comment: Where you say, "Suppose `n=0`, so for 4x4 matrix...", don't you mean "Suppose `i=0`, so for 4x4 matrix"?

Comment: If my understanding of the question is correct, I believe you could express it as follows. "Given positive integers `rows` and `cols`, let `mat` be a matrix with `r` rows and `c` columns, whose `i,j` element is the array `[i,j]`. Further, let `off` be a non-negative index offset. First extract from `mat` the submatrix `sub` comprised of rows and columns of `mat` having indices `off..r-1-off` and `off..c-1-off`, respectively"...

Comment: ..."Once this has been done compute and return an array containing  the elements on the "perimeter" of `sub`, beginning with the first column, in increasing row order, then the last row, in increasing column order, then then the last column, in decreasing row order and lastly the first row in decreasing column order. The "corner" elements of `sub` are not to be double-counted. How can I do that?"

Comment: This is really two separate questions. It would have been better to have asked each separately, with the second referencing the first. @sawa, as you left several comments above, I thought you might want to see my take on what is being asked. We'll see.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Maybe you are right, I could not express from bottom prerequisite. But it was supposed to consider **matrix is proper 2D** then you can consider it as square or rectangle. Just check **answer** I posted.

Comment: @sawa Maybe you will get clear Idea from answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work for both `m == n` & `m != n` case.

I hope, all will consider what matrix variable below stands for (2 D array)

```
def matrixRotation(matrix)
    m,n = matrix.length-1, matrix[0].length-1
    loop_count = [m,n].min/2
    0.upto(loop_count) do |i|
        indices = []
        i.upto(m-i) { |j| indices << [j, i] }
        i.upto(n-i) { |j| indices << [m-i, j] }
        i.upto(m-i) { |j| indices << [m-j, n-i] }
        i.upto(n-i) { |j| indices << [i, n-j] }
        puts "-------------- For Layer #{i+1} ---------------", nil
        indices = indices.uniq
        values = indices.map { |x| matrix[x[0]][x[1]] }
        puts 'indices:', indices.inspect, nil, 'values:', values.inspect
    end
end
```

Comment: The questions shows the "output" to be an array of pairs of indices whereas here you are displaying an array that contains the values from the array at those indices. It's a small point but please explain.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Actual my job was, I want to rotate each layer of matrix by some value and so I wanted Matrix layer elements in circular manner and in order so that I can rotate. So I was having problem to get indices array. Later part was easy.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Now I can rotate indices by `values[0,0] = values.pop(r%values.length)` which will rotate by `r` which can be 4, 36 etc. And then I will assign them to matrix by using indices and values (rotated).

Comment: If it’s a help, `arr.map(&:reverse).transpose` “rotates” an entire array `arr` 90 degrees.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are real good with matrix operation. It does rotate by `m` for `m x m` matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution, but I think there is a better way out there.

First define a method to print the matrix mapped by indexes, just to check if the result id correct:

```
def print_matrix(n,m)
  range_n, range_m = (0..n-1), (0..m-1)
  mapp = range_m.map { |y| range_n.map { |x| [x, y] } }
  mapp.each { |e| p e }
  puts "-" * 8 * n
end
```

Then define a method that returns the frame starting from the loop s (where 0 is the external frame):

```
def frame (n, m, s = 0)
  res = []
  return res if (s >= n/2 and s >= m/2) and (n.even? or m.even?)
  (s..n-s-1).each { |x| res << [x,s] }
  (s..m-s-1).each { |y| res << [res.last[0], y] }
  (res.last[0].downto s).each { |x| res << [x, res.last[1]] }
  (res.last[1].downto s).each { |y| res << [res.last[0], y] }
  res.uniq
end
```

Now, call the methods and check the output:

```
n, m, loops = 4, 4, 1
print_matrix(n,m)
frame(n, m, loops)

# [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]]
# [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
# [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]]
# [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
# --------------------------------
# [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) methods to advantage, specifically [Matrix::build](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-build), [Matrix#minor](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor) and [Matrix#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-5B-5D).

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def border_indices(nrows, ncols, i)
  m = Matrix.build(nrows, ncols) { |r,c| [r,c] }.minor(i..nrows-1-i, i..ncols-1-i)
  [[1,0,m.row_count-1], [0,1,m.column_count-1],
   [-1,0,m.row_count-1], [0,-1,m.column_count-2]].
    each_with_object([[0,0]]) do |(x,y,n),a|
      n.times { a << [a.last.first+x, a.last.last+y] }
    end.map { |i,j| m[i,j] }
end
```

**Examples**

```
nrows = 5
ncols = 6

border_indices(nrows, ncols, 0)
  #=> [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0],
  #    [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4],
  #    [4, 5], [3, 5], [2, 5], [1, 5],
  #    [0, 5], [0, 4], [0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
border_indices(nrows, ncols, 1)
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 1],
  #    [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3],
  #    [3, 4], [2, 4],
  #    [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
border_indices(nrows, ncols, 2)
  #=> [[2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

**Explanation**

Consider the calculation of `border_indices(5, 6, 1)`.

```
nrows = 5
ncols = 6
i = 1
mat = Matrix.build(nrows, ncols) { |r,c| [r,c] }
  #=> Matrix[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5]],
  #          [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]],
  #          [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5]],
  #          [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]],
  #          [[4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5]]]
m = mat.minor(i..nrows-1-i, i..ncols-1-i)
  #=> mat.minor(1..3, 1..4)
  #=> Matrix[[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]],
  #          [[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]],
  #          [[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4]]]
b = [[1,0,m.row_count-1], [0,1,m.column_count-1],
     [-1,0,m.row_count-1], [0,-1,m.column_count-2]]
  #=> [[1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 3], [-1, 0, 2], [0, -1, 2]]
c = b.each_with_object([[0,0]]) do |(x,y,n),a|
      n.times { a << [a.last.first+x, a.last.last+y] }
    end
  #=> [[0, 0], [1, 0],
  #    [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2],
  #    [2, 3], [1, 3],
  #    [0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
c.map { |i,j| m[i,j] }
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 1],
  #    [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3],
  #    [3, 4], [2, 4],
  #    [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Note that in the calculation of `c`, `a.last` is the last pair of indices added to the array being constructed (`a.last = [a.last.first, a.last.last]`).

Comment: I solved, checked in answers. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thanks prof, I never worked with `Matrix` functions, well introduced now :)